# PHP string to time conversion with GMT+Offset String

Tags: php

I used 'strtotime' function to convert 'gmt+offset' time string to actual time it returns this result. but actual time want to add offset but here, offset is minimized. so how to convert this gmt offset time in php? please help me solve this problem.

```
<?php
    echo date('H:i:s',strtotime("00:00:00+05:30"));
?>
```

result

> > 18:30:00

but actual time want to add offset with time, 05:30:00

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this:

```php
echo date('H:i:s',strtotime("11:00:00+05:30"));
```